# Setting up a connection between my DigitalOcean kubernetes cluster with an Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-rds, digital-ocean, amazon-vpc

I am trying to set up a connection between my DigitalOcean kubernetes cluster and the Amazon RDS.

I have created a postgresql DB instance with a VPC. My kubernetes resources are also in a VPC.

So I want my kubernetes nodes to be able to reach out to the Amazon RDS.

Is there a way to set this up?

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Whe you say a VPC do you mean the same VPC?

Comment: DigitalOcean and AWS are different. I have kubernetes cluster in DigitalOcean with a VPC and the RDS with VPC is in AWS.

Comment: ahh okey sorry for the miss understanding, but i think you should mention if it is public or private vpcs.

Comment: @testtest What have you tried so far? Any errors/issues? If it's a different clouds, then you need to expose database via `loadbalancer` e.g. and then connect to it since it will be publicly available + then adjust firewall rules to make it safe.

Answer (score 0):

VPC networks provide a more secure connection between resources because the network is inaccessible from the public internet and other VPC networks.
Possible solutions:
Note: The managed db and k8s cluster must be in the same region in your account (AWS or DO).

1. To solve that problem you could move your kubernetes cluster to AWS and add it in the same VPC as your db.
2. Or Move your managed db to digital ocean and add it in the same VPC with the k8s cluster.
3. Or use a public network instead to connect from k8s do cluster to AWS managed db.
4. Look at this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/communicating-between-two-vpc-in-the-same-region has some answers for your problem.